# LINQ Select Question

Tags: linq

I have a `List<SomeType>` where

`SomeType.Value` = "TASK?" where '?' can be from 1 to N.

`SomeType.Value` can also have values like TASKCNT, TASKOLD etc..

The question is how do I Select all "TASK?" ignoring other values like TASKCNT, TASKOLD

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a simple LINQ to objects, you can just use a regular expression:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^TASK\d$");
var tasks = 
    from task in theTasks
    where regex.IsMatch(task.Value);
    select task;
```